# Asus laptop with NVidia card shows two monitors

Tags: windows-7

Asus laptop, Nvidia card. Every once in a while, my display becomes less responsive, I go to display properties and see two displays there (identify shows 1/2 on my main display)

[image]

if I change the duplicate my displays to something else, I see the name of the second display - NVD SIM DISP

[image]

Comment: First things first - are you running t he latest drivers? And what model is your card?

Comment: @OliverG - I was running on pretty recent drivers, I upgraded a few days ago and for now it looks ok, but the problem was very intermittent, so I guess I'll have to wait and see if it comes back. Card is GTX560M

Comment: Did you set the display to 'mirror/duplicate' rather thane extended?